# Seemingly inconsistent output from `top` re: Swap header vs. SWAP column

Tags: ubuntu, memory, ubuntu-12.04, virtual-memory

How should I interpret this seemingly inconsistent output from `top` re: swap?

[image: Seemingly inconsistent output from top]

Running `free` confirms that no swap space is in use:

```
$ free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:         32098       4938      27159          0        216       1012
-/+ buffers/cache:       3709      28389
Swap:        15223          0      15223
```